# one Wildcard App ID for my apps?

Tags: ios

I have read multiple articles on Wildcard App IDs but i'm still Wonder...
I am going to publish several apps using Wildcard App ID.

Do i have to generate one app ID for each app like this (in member center)

```
name:      ID:
appname1  com.domain.*
appname2  com.domain.*
appname3  com.domain.*
```

or just one with for ex Company name like this. (and use this in all apps.)

```
name:         ID:
companyname   com.domain.*
```

Comment: Did you tried to create multiple appid with same identifier ?

Comment: It's highly recommended to use a unqiue App ID for each of your apps (e.g. `com.company.app1`, `com.company.app2`, etc.). It's way more flexible and you can add features such as iCloud later. Once you've published you app you **cannot change the App ID**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create a single wildcard profile. (Also you can't create multiple profile with same identifier).

Also remember that if you use Wild Card App Id you can't implement the following features in your app:

1. Push Notification
2. In App Purchase
3. iCloud